# Get posts by Taxonomy without terms

Tags: custom-taxonomy

Is there a way to get posts from a custom taxonomy **without specifying a term**?

I have a custom taxonomy called `media_category` and I want to get all the attachments which use this taxonomy since I have some attachments which doesnt use this taxonomy at all.

Answer (score 1):

You may do it by this method.

---

```
$media_category = get_terms('media_category');
foreach($media_category as $cat) {
    wp_reset_query();
    $args = array('post_type' => 'your_post_type',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'media_category',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $cat->slug,
            ),
        ),
     );
   $loop = new WP_Query($args);
     if($loop->have_posts()) {
      //  echo $cat->name;
        while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
            echo get_the_title();
        endwhile;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy_name',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => '22'
        )
    )
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    //content
endwhile;
?>
```

[more check out here about Taxonomy Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters)

Comment: But you are passing 'term_id = 22' in this query, i need *all* the terms

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a taxonomy archive by doing something like this:

1) In the theme directory create a file named **taxonomy-media_category.php** with the archive loop like...

```
<?php
get_header(); ?>

<div id="container">
    <div id="content" role="main">

        <?php the_post(); ?>
        <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

        <?php get_search_form(); ?>

        <h2>Archives by Month:</h2>
        <ul>
            <?php //SOME OF YOUR CODE HERE ?>
        </ul>

    </div><!-- #content -->
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

2) In the loop, you can change the code as needed

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I used this:

```
$taxonomy = 'MY_TAXONOMY_HERE';

// Get all the terms of that taxonomy
$terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, 'orderby=count&hide_empty=1' );

$args = array_merge( $args, [
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => wp_list_pluck( $terms, 'term_id' )
        )
    )
]);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```